# Pass open file request to operating system in PHP

Tags: php, file, user-interface

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way in PHP to open a file on a user's desktop (i.e., the user select a file from a file list shown on a PHP page, and then the file opens with the appropriate program on the user's desktop as if the user had double-clicked it in the GUI.) After searching for a while, I discovered that this is possible via some convoluted-looking code using the COM object in PHP, but that's only going to work for Windows users and I'm trying to keep this platform agnostic.

Has anyone else ever tried to do this and succeeded?

Comment: Would the user have some kind of software on their machines or do you want it to work for any Joe who visits the site? Because I'd wager the latter is impossible (and probably intentionally so, that could be an extremely dangerous operation to allow).

Comment: @MrLore: I've already considered the security issues with this which is why I'm not hopeful that there's a way to do it--at least not easily.

I'm trying to create a PHP system for users at my workplace where they can pull up a list of files in their browser (the files would be on a network share) and they could chose a file from that list and it would open for them for editing as if they had double-clicked it. So, kind of a simple file management system. 

Probably going to have to find another way to do this but I thought it worth asking.

Comment: If it's at your work, then surely you can install something on the computers you want the functionality on? If so, maybe take a look at Seth's answer on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200398/launch-file-on-clients-computer-from-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't execute an application on the user's machine without either a lengthy "user consent" process, or the user voluntarily (and, ideally, knowingly) installing some software component.

I think the cleanest way might be to use a (signed!) Java applet.

Otherwise you could try and make the user register a specific protocol, with a suitable protocol handler, that you would let download and install on the user's system to intercept a link such as `exec://format%20C%2C` ;-)

Unfortunately, the file:// protocol is (understandably) restricted. For example, in Firefox it will work (somewhat) if you insert manually "C:\" in the address bar and navigate. If you click on *those* links they will (somewhat) work. Copy the same links in a document in a different security context (e.g. Internet) and lo and behold, it won't work.

Another possibility would be to backdoor all the intranet clients with, um, REXECd (available on most platforms) or some clone. Then when the user clicks, you send the command from PHP to the user's workstation. Since nowadays PC's are multiuser platforms, you'll need some quick legwork to determine how to do the deed. E.g. on a Linux box you'd have to run a X application with the appropriate ownership and `DISPLAY` value.

You could also "recognize" the user's platform and let the user download an appropriate batch file, either `.sh` or `.bat` or `.cmd`; but they would need a click to download, one to approve, one to open the executable.

Comment: Ah, some excellent ideas that I hadn't considered. I'm sure one of those will work in some form or another for my situation. Thanks so much for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run files on client. It's a big security hole and browser will not allow you do that.

On windows you can use ActiveX, but client must allow installing ActiveX component, and you will have many problems with it.